# Understanding Python's concurrency

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm missing some small, yet extremely crucial point in why concurrency in Python is nonblocking.
I understand that there is a scheduler, that manages async functions, and that the concurrency is cooperative: the async function should return control back for the scheduler not to hang (i.e. be nonblocking).

What I do not understand, is why, for instance, `asyncio.sleep()` is "nonblocking". If it is being executed, one cannot run any other code. Consider the following example:

```py
import asyncio
from time import perf_counter


async def main():
    # case A
    start = perf_counter()
    await asyncio.sleep(5) # task #1
    await asyncio.sleep(5) # task #2
    print(perf_counter() - start) # 10

    # case B
    start = perf_counter()
    await asyncio.gather(*(
        asyncio.sleep(5), asyncio.sleep(5)
    ))
    print(perf_counter() - start) # 5

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Why does the scheduler schedule all the tasks in case **B** so they are running concurrently, but not in case **A**?
Isn't `task #1` "blocking" the program execution? (because one can do nothing but wait for the `task #1` to complete)

In the example above I expect `task #1` to return the control back, so that the `task #2` will start executing, but it doesn't happen... Why? Because the loop is busy executing `task #1`, so it cannot start executing `task #2`? Why does the same not happen with `gather()`?

Comment: This question is getting pretty vague to be considered within bounds here, but the key is `await` which signals that the process should block further execution.  In A it blocks each, in B `await` is on the `gather` and not the individual tasks, so it goes "schedule 1, schedule 2, wait for gather to finish"

Comment: @possum That makes sense, but then what's the difference between sequental and concurrent code? The latter allows a program to run a group of tasks concurrently while remaining "sequental"? (I'm omitting more advanced usage of concurrency here)

Comment: Think of a network server serving multiple clients. Each client is a task that can run concurrently. But these tasks will spend most time being blocked waiting for network data or waiting until the output buffers can accept more data. The event loop allows them to be blocked and unblocked in random order and serve their clients in only one hardware thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [task](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) is different from a [coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3.8/glossary.html#term-coroutine). You launch one coroutine, your `main` as your only task at the beginning. A task is something that is scheduled to run in the event loop concurrently to the current task.

`asyncio.sleep()` is not a task, [it is a coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping). You `await` this coroutine. This tells the event loop that the surrounding coroutine (the `main`) cannot continue until that `sleep` coroutine is done.

Since you explicitly blocked your `main` coroutine on that first `sleep`, the second `sleep` is started after the first completes.

A `sleep` coroutine does not actually put the thread to sleep. It instead communicates to the event loop that it is blocked until a certain amount of time has passed. If the event loop contains any other tasks that are not blocked, it will process those in the mean time. Otherwise the event loop will block and wait until the earliest timeout occurs.

This second part explains what's happening in `await asyncio.gather(*(asyncio.sleep(5), asyncio.sleep(5)))`. `gather` schedules all given arguments as concurrent tasks. Therefore both sleeps start at the same time, so they finish at the same time.

Think of the event loop as three sets of objects: A set of tasks that can currently run, a set of tasks that are blocked, and a set of events that it can wait for to change blocked tasks to runnable tasks. `await asyncio.sleep()` simply tells the event loop that the current task is blocked until a suitable timeout event has occurred.

### Follow-up questions

> "If the event loop contains any other tasks that are not blocked, it will process those in the mean time" - could you please provide such an example in code?

This has three tasks. Two will periodically print messages 10 times until it is cancelled. The main task blocks on a time-out and stops the other tasks.

```py
import asyncio


async def say(message):
    while True:
        print(message)
        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            return


async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(say("Hello"))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(say("handsome"))
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    task1.cancel()
    task2.cancel()
    await asyncio.gather(task1, task2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

A more common use-case would be a TCP network server. The main task waits on the listening socket. Each new client connection is turned into a new task. Each task uses the asyncio to wait for incoming data or to transfer data to the client without blocking. The event loop will automatically switch between tasks whenever a socket becomes unblocked.

Comment: "If the event loop contains any other tasks that are not blocked, it will process those in the mean time" - could you please provide such an example in code? I was expecting such a behaviour in case **A**, but as you wrote `asyncio.sleep()` blocks the loop

Comment: @bzz hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! So by `.create_task()` we're telling the scheduler to wrap the coro into task and run it when the scheduler has time. By `.sleep(10)` we're creating such an opportunity, so the scheduled tasks got time to run. In the coro itself we're making another opportunity by `.sleep(1)`. Is my understanding correct? Any particular reason for `.gather()`?

Comment: @bzz yes, your understanding is correct. No particular reason for that `gather` or the `cancel`. Tasks get cancelled anyway when the main task returns. It just makes it more explicit and gives an opportunity to return results or exceptions from the tasks to the main task.

Comment: So, basically, `await coro` blocks the execution flow until that coro is finished; the loop is not blocked (as long as the coro is nonblocking). As soon as that coro starts "waiting", it gives the opportunity to other tasks in the loop to run. When that coro finishes, the execution flow continues, while the loop "blocks" until given another opportunity. Is that correct?

Comment: @bzz Yes, that's exactly what's going on.